# AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'setWindowFlags'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I can't use `setWindowFlags` with my `QDialog` widget. am trying to hide the close button or remove the whole frame so the user can't close it using the default method.

I've tried adding one of those two lines inside the `setupUi` function for my class :

`self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

and

`self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint, False)` but both gave me the same error.

Here is my code for a better inspection:

```py
import os
import sys

import psycopg2
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox

import backoffice


class Ui_Dialog(object):

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 274)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.resource_path("./images/pos_logo_small.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal,
                       QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)
        Dialog.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background:#a1d0f4;")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.formLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(4)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.label_3)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background:white;")
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(2, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.lineEdit_2)
        self.closeToolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.closeToolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.closeToolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.closeToolButton.setFont(font)
        self.closeToolButton.setStyleSheet("background:red;color:white;")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.resource_path("./images/close-window-256.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal,
                        QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.closeToolButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.closeToolButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.closeToolButton.setObjectName("closeToolButton")
        self.closeToolButton.clicked.connect(self.exit_app)
        self.formLayout.setWidget(4, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.closeToolButton)
        self.logInToolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(Dialog)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.logInToolButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.logInToolButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Shorooq_N1")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.logInToolButton.setFont(font)
        self.logInToolButton.setStyleSheet("background:#0a74c4;color:white;")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(self.resource_path("./images/check-mark-11-256.ico")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal,
                        QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.logInToolButton.setIcon(icon2)
        self.logInToolButton.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextUnderIcon)
        self.logInToolButton.setObjectName("logInToolButton")
        self.dialog = Dialog
        self.logInToolButton.clicked.connect(self.log_in)
        self.formLayout.setWidget(3, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.logInToolButton)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.formLayout, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def exit_app(self):
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit()

    def log_in(self):
        print('activated')
        try:
            connection = psycopg2.connect(user="*******",
                                          password="********",
                                          host="127.0.0.1",
                                          port="5432",
                                          database="********")
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from users"
            cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
            print("Selecting rows from users table using cursor.fetchall")
            user_records = cursor.fetchall()
            print("Print each row and it's columns values")
            input_username = self.lineEdit.text()
            input_password = self.lineEdit_2.text()
            for row in user_records:
                if row[1] == input_username:
                    if row[2] == input_password:
                        backoffice.isAuthenticated = True
                        print('logged in ')
                        self.dialog.close()
                else:
                    pass
                print(input)
        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
        finally:
            # closing database connection.
            connection = psycopg2.connect(user="*********",
                                          password="*******",
                                          host="127.0.0.1",
                                          port="5432",
                                          database="*******")
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            if (connection):
                cursor.close()
                connection.close()
                print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Vision Store Manager"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "إسم المستخدم"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "كلمة المرور"))
        self.closeToolButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "خروج"))
        self.logInToolButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "تسجيل الدخول"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog",
                                      "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/images/images/logo_small.png\"/></p></body></html>"))

    @staticmethod
    def resource_path(relative_path):
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


import login_rcs_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()

    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Getting the error `AttributeError: 'Ui_Dialog' object has no attribute 'setWindowFlags'` when executing the line : `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

***UPDATE***

I changed :
`self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`
To

```
the_login = QtWidgets.QDialog
the_login.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

and the error now is:`TypeError: setWindowFlags(self, Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType]): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget'`

Comment: you might forgot to inherit some parent class from your UI_Dialog

Comment: @Vova i changed it to inherit a parent class and it gave me the error `TypeError: setWindowFlags(self, Union[Qt.WindowFlags, Qt.WindowType]): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWidget`   check update please

Comment: Based on [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309352/how-to-fix-error-in-my-pyqt-programm-first-argument-of-unbound-method-must-have) I changed this line to be like : `Dialog.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)` and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You do your inheritance wrong.

How it should be in declarations?
class `Ui_Dialog` should inherit all properties from `QtWidgets.QDialog`. Your `Dialog` variable should be `self`. You shouldn't call your functions with `Dialog` variable.

Your main mistakes:

```
class Ui_Dialog => class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog)
self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog) => self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self) 
#all should be changed like this
ui.setupUi(Dialog)=>ui.setupUi()
```

Code:

```
class Ui_Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setObjectName("Dialog")
        self.resize(400, 274)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        ... #your stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()

    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: it gives me the error `TypeError: setupUi() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Dialog'` and when I changed to `setupUi(Dialog)` it showed up but just an empty window none of the components appeared!

Comment: change all function's signature - delete `Dialog` from all. (from `setupUi` and `retranslateUi` - and replace `Dialog` to `self`